# Unreasonable orphans in lines (classicthesis)

Tags: lyx, margins, classicthesis

I am using classicthesis in Lyx, and I run into some weird orphans.

From what I can see, there are no reasons for them to occur (see image for two examples).

[image: Problem]

I am using this package in my preamble:

\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm]{geometry}

Comment: Are you referring to the words sticking into the margin? Add something like `\hyphenation{chemo-kines}` in the preamble for correcting the first, since TeX seems not able to hyphenate `chemokines`; for the second, use `\slash` instead of `/` before `Swiss`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typographic “orphan” is the first line of a paragraph that happens to fall at the end of a page; it's an orphan because “it has no past, but has a future”. The converse, that is the last line of a paragraph in a new page is a “widow”, because “it has a past, but no future”.

Words sticking into the margin have no name, because they are simply typesetting errors to be corrected. They may happen because TeX sometimes finds no way to typeset a paragraph other than signalling it has a problem; in this cases it will also warn about an `Overfull \hbox`.

You can cure the first problem by adding

```
\hyphenation{chemo-kine chemo-kines}
```

to your preamble (that is, before `\begin{document}`). This helps TeX that is unable to hyphenate the word `chemokine` and its plural; somehow it slips through the hyphenation patterns. I checked and it's not even in the big list of known hyphenation exceptions.

The second overfull line might be cured by typing

```
UniProtKB\slash Swiss-Prot
```

so that TeX will be allowed to break the line after the slash.

Comment: having taken a look at the rest of the text shown in the example, it's a fact that many other words would not be hyphenated by the tex patterns.  most exceptions from technical fields in the "big list" that egreg mentions are from math, physics, or computer science.  the life sciences and chemistry aren't nearly so well covered.  if someone finds an exception that's not in the [big list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf), report it to `tugboat@tug.org` and it will be considered for addition to the list.

Comment: i've posted all the non-hyphenatable words from this example for attention in the next "big list" update, so that's a start.

Comment: @barbarabeeton chemical compound names though are very regular so might be more amenable to having an extended (or different) hyphenation pattern rather than treating as a long list of exceptions. `\usepackage[chemistry]{babel}` ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- good point.  i shall look into that.